# Enviar JSON para uma variável fora da função

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Meus conhecimentos são vagos nessa área, preciso de uma ajudinha!

Como faço para para pegar o resultado que recebi (JSON) e passar para uma variável. fora da function, ainda estou aprendendo.

Mas fácil postar o código, tenho um JS que faz toda a parte de mostrar vídeos, estilo Stories.

Funciona normalmente assim:

```js
<script>
var myPlaylist = [{"title": "Title","date": "11/8 2:34:4","url": "/stories/storie/0811201914357.mov","icon": "logo.jpg"}];

var socialStory = new Story({
 playlist: myPlaylist
});

</script>
```

Mas já tenho uma API que gera um JSON pra mim e quero jogar em var myPlaylist,
segue o que tenho até o momento, mas não sei como enviar os dados pra myPlaylist

```js
<img class="profile" onclick="stories.launch();" src="logo.jpg" />
<div id="storytime"></div>
<script>
    function carrega(){
        var url = "stories.asp";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
            url: url,
            timeout: 3000,
            datatype: 'JSON',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
            },
            error: function() {
            },
            success: function(json) {

                    console.log(json.stories)
                    // me retorna assim
                    //{"title": "Title","date": "11/8 2:34:4","url": "/stories/storie/0811201914357.mov","icon": "logo.jpg"}
            } 
        });  
    }
    
    var myPlaylist = [?????????];

    var stories = new Story({
        playlist: myPlaylist
    });
</script>
```

Não posso trocar o stories.launch, stories e Story porque o JS está esperando eles. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado antecipadamente pela grande ajuda!

Comment: que hora que você chama a função `carrega()`?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode dar um `myPlaylist.push(json.stories)`, como myPlaylist está declarada como um array no escopo principal você pode chama-lo sem problemas dentro da sua função.

ficaria dessa forma no seu código:

```
function carrega() {
        var url = "stories.asp";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            timeout: 3000,
            datatype: 'JSON',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            error: function () {
            },
            success: function (json) {

                myPlaylist.push(json.stories)
                console.log(myPlaylist)

            }
        });
    }
```